# Failed to upload mp4 files in PHP

Tags: php, zend-framework3, laminas

am trying to upload .mp4 files with php but it's not working. Here's the script:

**PHP Class to handle the upload:**

class CustomFileUpload
{

```
public static function upload($data)
{
    $errors = [];
    $response = [];
    $file = htmlentities(trim($data['file']['name']), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    $tmpDir = $data['file']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $data['file']['size'];
    $fileExt = strtolower(pathinfo($file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    $validExtensions = ['mp3', 'mp4'];
    $uploadDir = '';
    if ($fileExt == "mp4") {
        $uploadDir = './public/ex-media/videos/';
    } elseif ($fileExt == "mp3") {
        $uploadDir = './public/ex-media/audios/';
    } else {
        $errors['msg'] = 'file type not allowed.';
        $response['status'] = 407;
        $response['msg'] = "error";
        $response['error'] = $errors;

        return $response;
    }

    if(!in_array($fileExt,$validExtensions))
    {
        $errors['msg'] = "Invalid extension detected for selected image file, please use a supported image extension.";
        $errors['ext-detected'] = $fileExt;
    }

    if(empty($errors))
    {
        $uuid = explode("-", $data['uuid']);
        $fileNewName = $uuid[0]."-".time().".".$fileExt;

        var_dump($tmpDir);
        exit();

        $moved = move_uploaded_file($tmpDir, $uploadDir.$fileNewName);

        if ($moved) {
            $response['status'] = 200;
            $response['msg'] = "success";
            $response['fileUrl'] = $fileNewName;

            echo('heres ur newly uploaded file - '.$fileNewName);
            exit();

            return $response;
        } else {
            $response['status'] = 502;
            $response['msg'] = "failed";
            $response['error'] = "upload failed for UNKNOWN reasons!";

            echo('error while uploading file - go to CustomFileUpload.php');
            exit();

            return $response;
        }
    }
    else {
        $response['status'] = 407;
        $response['msg'] = "error";
        $response['error'] = $errors;

        return $response;
    }
}
```

}

PHP Controller Action that calls the CustomFileUpload class:

```
public function uploadAction()
{
    $response = ['status_code' => 404];
    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost())
    {
        $data = $this->params()->fromPost();

        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $data = array_merge_recursive(
            $request->getPost()->toArray(),
            $request->getFiles()->toArray()
        );

        $fileUpload = CustomFileUpload::upload($data);
    }

    return new JsonModel($response);
}
```

If I upload an mp3 file, it works perfectly but for mp4, it's the opposite. So I tried to dump the content of the tmp_dir `var_dump($tmpDir);  exit();` as seen the CustomFileUpload class. After doing this, it turns out that the `tmp_dir` is empty for mp4 files which is not so for the mp3 files as seen in the screenshots below (taken from Postman).

tmp_dir IS NOT EMPTY for mp3 file:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsEQQ.png)

tmp_dir IS EMPTY for mp3 file:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojd4T.png)

Please, how do I fix these?

Comment: Probably not related to file types, but file _sizes_, and the upload limit configured in your system. Do a var_dump of $data['file'] (I’m assuming that’s just some sort of framework wrapper for $_FILES?), and look at the result with https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php in mind.

Comment: like @CBroe mentioned, you can try to upload a mini (less than 64KB) mp4 file first. And then can be sure if it's a file-size problem or not. Typically there is a PHP upload file size limit and POST size limit, like 1MB or so.

Comment: Yes, you both were right, I had to increase my server file upload limits and the problem was solved. Thanks alot!